# Restoring SQL table into new table with more columns

Tags: sql, mysql, gitorious

I'm trying to salvage a [Gitorious](http://getgitorious.com/) installation that has gone bad. I've dumped the SQL table using `mysqldump`, but now I'm running into the problem that the new version of Gitorious changed its SQL schema in a few places.

In particular, the old version has a table `taggings`, which looks like

```
mysql> describe taggings;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tag_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| taggable_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| taggable_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the new version, this table has gotten three extra columns:

```
mysql> describe taggings;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tag_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| taggable_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| taggable_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tagger_id     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tagger_type   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| context       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

so that

```
grep 'INSERT INTO `taggings`' inuse.sql | mysql -uroot gitorious_production
```

fails with

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 1: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Is there an easy way to tell MySQL that the final two fields should be left at their default value, `NULL`?

(The new Gitorious' `taggings` table starts out empty.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general best practice, you should mention the field names in which you're inserting :

```
Insert into taggings (id,tag_id,taggable_id,taggable_type,created_at) values (...your values...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your new table taggings as taggings_old

Create a table named taggings with your old schema

Insert your data

Add the new column to your table taggings